# GD.SE's Winter GameJam - Should we accept non-web games too?

Tags: discussion, gamejam-2014-winter

The previous jam only permitted web-based games. The decision was taken after we took into consideration that web-based games have few dependencies and generally don't pose a threat for the player's system. At most, you need a browser and a player such as Flash Player or Unity Player.

If we were to lift this requirement, would you willingly download games as executables and run them? Vote on the answer that applies to you.

Comment: Accepted Trevor's answer on 8 Jan 2014.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Gamedev.stackexchange.com](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) site is about developing games.  *Any sort of games.*

We allow questions about all sorts of languages, about the creation of downloadable games, about PC games, about mobile games, about freely downloadable games and about commercial games.  We have questions about DirectX, about OpenGL, about Unity, about GameMaker, about Flash, about XNA, about Construct, and dozens of other languages, tools, and platforms.

Why in the world would we want to limit participation in the site's events to just one small fraction of our users?

No -- our site events should be inclusive.  Participating in a game jam isn't about winning -- it's about participating;  about meeting people.  Showing people what you can do and admiring what they can do.  It's about being a part of a community.

We should be celebrating the people who make this site what it is.  Not excluding people on the basis of who we think won't get many votes and therefore shouldn't be allowed to enter in the first place.

Consider this a vote for "don't splinter the community".

Comment: You've swayed my vote. I agree that should allow any platform.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, I am okay with downloading and running executables as well as any requirements they come with, from the jam's participants.

Comment: I'm for this, but my only fear would be that users would play more browser based games rather than downloadable ones because they are quicker to start, meaning they may get more votes.

Comment: Yep, a standard format for submission allows each game an equal chance of being judged. I think it's a mistake to not require a web entry. It's fine to accept builds for other platforms, but a web version should be included.

Answer (score 1):

No, I'd rather the jam was limited to web games.